# How to iterate a string in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I am trying to get each character of a string and do some formatting and produce a new string in Ballerina. How can I iterate character-wise ?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ballerina 0.975.0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the available [string functions](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/primitive-types.html#string), I could come up with the following solutions.

Solution 1:

```
string s = "This is my string";
foreach c in s.split("") {
    io:println(c);    
}
```

Solution 2:

```
string s = "This is my string";
foreach i in 0..< lengthof s {
    io:println(s.substring(i, i+1));     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the more recent Ballerina versions (currently 2201.8 Swan Lake Update 8) the correct way is:

```
string s = "This is my string";
foreach string c in s {
    io:println(c);    
}
```